# What tilaka do god Parshurama wear?

Tags: parashurama, tilak, symbols

Parshurama, is generally listed as the 6th of the famous ten incarnations (descensions/avatara) of god Vishnu.

Parshurama is an ardent devotee of god Shiva and his student too. So it logically makes sense, he would generally wear a Tripuṇḍra Tilaka on his forehead.

However, as is generally the case with most iconographic depictions of Vishnu's different avataras, they are depicted as wearing the Vaishnava Urdhvapuṇḍraka Tilaka.

In a standard Google [image-search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=parshuram&client=ms-opera-mobile&channel=new&espv=1&prmd=inmv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcr8SI5LD3AhWnILcAHVNyBvQQ_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=393&bih=688&dpr=2.75) one may find, Parshurama wearing both, sometimes Tripuṇḍra, other times Urdhvapuṇḍraka, and sometimes some other kinds of Tilakas too.

In any case, **I'd like direct textual references as to what Tilaka do Parshurama wears? Is it Tripuṇḍra, or Urdhvapuṇḍra?**

How should he be portrayed in the murtis (idols), or images/paintings, as per the relevant texts?

Consider providing either direct verses from Purāṇas or Aagamas, or any text that depict the iconography or depiction of god Parshurama.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Śrī Rāmacaritamānasa by Goswami Tulsidas, Paraśurāma is described wearing the Śaivaite Tripuṇḍra tilaka.

After Śrī Rāma breaks the Śiva's bow ([RCM 1.262.4](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/page/n270/mode/1up?view=theater)), in the svayamvara of goddess Sītā, Paraśurāma arrives, and Tulsidas-ji describes his demeanour as follows -

> Balakanda - [1.268](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/page/n275/mode/1up?view=theater), Rāmacaritamānasa
>
> चौपाई
>
> खरभरु देखि बिकल पुर नारीं। सब मिलि देहिं महीपन्ह गारीं।। तेहिं अवसर
> सुनि सिव धनु भंगा। आयसु भृगुकुल कमल पतंगा।। देखि महीप सकल सकुचाने। बाज
> झपट जनु लवा लुकाने।। गौरि सरीर भूति भल भ्राजा। **भाल बिसाल त्रिपुंड
> बिराजा।।** सीस जटा ससिबदनु सुहावा। रिसबस कछुक अरुन होइ आवा।। भृकुटी
> कुटिल नयन रिस राते। सहजहुँ चितवत मनहुँ रिसाते।। बृषभ कंध उर बाहु
> बिसाला। चारु जनेउ माल मृगछाला।। कटि मुनि बसन तून दुइ बाँधें। धनु सर कर
> कुठारु कल काँधें।।
>
> > Seeing the uproar the women of the city were all distressed and joined
> > in cursing the princes. The very moment arrived the sage Paraśurāma, a
> > very sun to the lotus-like race of Bhṛgu, led by the news of the
> > breaking of the bow. At his very sight the kings all cowered down even
> > as a quail would shrink beneath the swoop of a hawk. A coat of ashes
> > looked most charming on his fair body: **his broad forehead was
> > adorned with a Tripuṇḍra (as peculiar mark consisting of three
> > horizontal lines, sacred to Śiva)**. Having matted locks on the head,
> > his handsome moonlike face was a bit reddened with anger; with knitted
> > brows and eyes inflamed with passion, his natural look gave one the
> > impression that he was enraged. He had well-built shoulders like those
> > of a bull and a broad chest and long arms; he was adorned with a
> > beautiful sacred thread, rosary and deerskin. With an anchorte's
> > covering about his loins and a pair of quivers fastened by his side,
> > he held a bow and arrows in his hands and an axe upon his fair
> > shoulder.
>
> English Translation by Gita Press Gorakhpur

**So, as per Śrī Rāmacaritamānasa , Paraśurāma wears the Tripuṇḍra tilaka.**

Comment: Rama did not break Siva's bow.

Comment: Please, @SK , kindly read the preceding chapters of Ramacharitamanasa, before making saying that -"Rama did not break Siva's bow"_. **He did**. Gods do it all time. Sri Virabhadra swallowed Vishnu's discus too. It's all divine play.

Comment: मुदित कहहिं जहँ तहँ नर नारी। भंजेउ राम संभुधनु भारी।। == **Everywhere men and women in their joy kept saying that Rama had broken the massive bow of Sambhu.** [Gita Press Translations](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/page/n270/mode/1up?view=theater)

Comment: "saying that -"Rama did not break Siva's bow"_. He did." that is an interpretation.  other interpretations abound on the 'net.